# Trying to sort a list by values closest to zero, using absolute value in python

Tags: python

I've spent quite some time searching to see if there was a similar issue. Unfortunately, I couldn't just comment on the previously asked question to see why my attempt was not working. 
On this site there exists a question where a person wants to sort a list, according to closest numbers to a specific value.
    his example:*not verbatim copying his example but putting a working solution*

```
list_x = [1,2,5,11]
list_x.sort(key = lambda x: abs(x-4))
```

which will return the list sorted by values closest to 4 `(5,2,1,11)`
However, when trying to sort a much larger list by values closest to zero this is happening to me:

```
listA.sort(key = lambda x: abs(x))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#382>", line 1, in <module>
    listA.sort(key = lambda x: abs(x))
  File "<pyshell#382>", line 1, in <lambda>
    listA.sort(key = lambda x: abs(x))
TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'str'
```

What exactly am I doing incorrectly thats preventing the list from being sorted by absolute values?

This is input data for what makes listA

```
for i in decrange(0, 13, i):
   code = (func(seq, float(i)))
   codes = '%.3f' % code
   listA.append(float(codes))
   listB.append(str(codes))
listA.sort(key = lambda k: abs(k))
x = listA[0]
answer = listB.index(x) * float(.01)
```

Comment: you have strings in your 'larger' `list`...

Comment: The input data would be helpful here.  You may also call `abs(int(x))`.

Comment: Thanks for editting it, I was in middle of the process of trying to fix it XD.

Comment: Googling for "bad operand type for abs(): 'str'" gives a helpful answer on the very first result.

Comment: decrange is just a range function allowing for smaller steps, i =.01 in this case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you're getting seems fairly self-explanatory:

```
TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'str'
```

It looks like somewhere in your list you have a string value instead of a numeric value.  This will work (assuming integer values):

```
listA.sort(key = lambda x: abs(int(x)))
```

...but it would be better to figure out why your list has strings in it and fix *that* instead.

Comment: I thought by floating codes it would convert  it to values. listA.append(int(codes)) then would be the correct coding I suppose?

Comment: Calling `float()` should accomplish the same thing.  And using `int()` vs `float()` depends on whether you expect integer values or floating point values.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out those larsks, been working on this program for quite some time. Only programmed simple perl like 8 years ago, and  taking a python course. Appreciate the assistance

Comment: If this answer helped out, please take a moment to mark it as accepted by clicking on the check mark to the left of the answer.  Thanks!